# Javascript apply source code (Hypothetically, do not want to implement)

Tags: javascript

So I know what the `apply()` function does in javascript, but if you were to implement it on your own, how would you do that? Preferably don't use bind, since that's pretty dependent on apply.

NOTE: I'm asking out of curiosity, I don't want to actually do this.

Comment: Wow, not sure who downvoted this question, but I still really want to know the answer.

Comment: I can imagine being able to do it with some `eval` or similar-style hackery, but that aside, you can’t do it. It’s a fundamental part of the language that the interpreter itself implements as a built-in for a good reason.

Comment: Yeah I've heard that one as well. Too bad people downvoted, I don't think it's a bad question and I'd like to know what other people think

Comment: they might be down voting due to this statement: "Preferably don't use bind, since that's pretty dependent on apply", because that is not necessarily true, unless I'm misunderstanding what you are saying.

Comment: Is it the setting `this` part of `.apply()` you want to implement, or the passing all the arguments as an array part of `.apply()` that you want to implement? Or both? Are you allowed to use `.call()`?

Comment: @GeorgettePincin maybe, I put that there because if you use bind it's pretty easy

Comment: And @nnnnnn pretty much both, sure you can use `call()`

Comment: I don't see how using .call is much better because you are just basically turning .call into .apply...which isn't very valuable? I honestly thought you were asking what the logic would look like underneath the hood, which would be interesting.

Comment: @GeorgettePincin I said you could use cal since I don't think it'd be that easy to turn it into apply haha. But yeah, I'm curious of what the actual implementation is like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with `eval`:

```
Function.prototype.myApply = function(thisVal, args) {
    return eval('this.call(thisVal' + args.map(function(arg, idx) { return ', args[' + idx + ']' }).join('') + ')');
};
```

…but please don’t do this. The browser-supplied `apply` implementation ought to be sufficient.

Comment: definitely, I was just thinking about it and wanted to know other people's thoughts. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 2):

you could try spread operator in ES6

```
Function.prototype.apply2 = function(obj, arg) {
  var t = typeof obj == 'object' && !!obj ? obj : window,
    res;
  t.__func__ = this;
  if(arg) {
    if(!Array.isArray(arg)) throw 'arg is not array';
    res = t.__func__(...arg);  //es6
  } else {
    res = t.__func__();
  }
  delete t.__func__;
  return res;
};
```